# Assigning the value to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have create one JSON

like

```
   $total_pages = 1;
    $device_details=array('devices'=> array(), 'total_pages');
     while ($rows_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_all_resultset))
            {
                $details =array('name' => $rows_fetch['name'], 'latitude' => $rows_fetch['currentLatitude'], 'longitude' => $rows_fetch['currentLongitude']);
            array_push($device_details['devices'],$details);
            }
array_push($device_details['total_pages'], $total_pages);
```

Here device details has been added but total pages will not be add to JSON and gives an Parse error

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `array_push` like that. Instead put it like below..

```
$device_details['total_pages'] = $total_pages;
```

It is not possible to insert a value on a particular key using `array_push`.

---

#### Illustration of `array_push` failure using a simple insert on a particular key.

```
<?php
$new=array();
array_push($new['car'],'hello');
print_r($new);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /tmp/execpad-cf3c45951562/source-cf3c45951562 on line 3
Array
(
    [car] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $total_pages = 1;
 // when you construct the array, do it.
 $device_details=array('devices'=> array(), 'total_pages' => $total_pages);
 while ($rows_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_all_resultset)) {
    $device_details['devices'][] = array(
          'name' => $rows_fetch['name'], 
          'latitude' => $rows_fetch['currentLatitude'], 
          'longitude' => $rows_fetch['currentLongitude']
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$device_details=array('devices'=> array(), 'total_pages');
```

Should be

```
$device_details=array('devices'=> array(), 'total_pages' => array());
```

if you want to use array push